# Inputbox someone press OK without entering anything

Tags: excel, inputbox, vba

I want to force my users to either enter a value or press cancel.

here is my current code but I can't find how to state the used pressed OK without entering anything.

Thanks

```
InputBox:
On Error GoTo Cancel
var_TauxUS = InputBox("Veuillez aller sur   www.xe.com   et entrer le taux d'echange US/CAN:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Exemple: 1,26 (avec une virgule)", "TAUX US")  'La variable reçoit la valeur entrée dans l'InputBox


    If StrPtr(var_TauxUS) = 0 Then
        GoTo InputBox
    ElseIf var_TauxUS <= 1 Then
        MsgBox "Vous devez entrer un chiffre plus grand que 1"
        GoTo InputBox
    ElseIf var_TauxUS >= 1.35 Then
        MsgBox "Vous devez entrer un chiffre plus petit que 1.36"
        GoTo InputBox
    Else
        var_TauxUS = var_TauxUS + vECHANGEDEVISE  'Calculer l'échange de la devise
        var_US = True
        MsgBox "Nous commenceons a updater les prix à un taux de " & var_TauxUS & " - Merci!"
        GoTo Programme
    End If
```

I tried:

```
IsEmpty(var_TauxUS)

If var_TauxUS = "" then
```

and it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample to get you started:

```
Sub test()
    Do
        var_TauxUS = InputBox("Enter here:")

        If StrPtr(var_TauxUS) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop While var_TauxUS = vbNullString
End Sub
```